# Using angular directive to add a class and also show/add an element

Tags: angularjs

I have a table where I want to highlight a row and show a warning symbol when certain input is fulfilled. I've made a directive for this.

```
<tr ng-repeat="size in resource.sizes" check-diameter size="size">
 <td><i class="fa fa-warning"></i>{{size.title}}</td>
 <td>{{size.inner}}</td>
 <td>{{size.outer}}</td>
</tr>

.directive('checkDiameter', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        size: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch('size', function(){
          if(scope.size.inner > scope.size.outer){
            element.addClass('warning');
          }
        }, true);

      }
    };
```

As it is now it highlights the row. But how do I also make the directive to show/add the warning symbol `<i class="fa fa-warning"></i>` ?

Normally I would use a ng-hide but I'm using the controller for several views so I need to put everything in the directive to keep it modular.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with ng-class and ng-hide?

Comment: @Wawy Can I point ng-hide to my directive instead of my controller somehow? I have two views for same controller. In one of them the 'sizes' subdocument does not exist. So if I run the logic in my controller it will produce an error in my view where sizez is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use ng-class to add the class in the element you want. If you want to do hide an element based on the same condition you need to use css.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="size in resource.sizes" ng-class="{warning: size.inner > size.outer}">
 <td><i class="fa fa-warning warning-message"></i>{{size.title}}</td>
 <td>{{size.inner}}</td>
 <td>{{size.outer}}</td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
.directive('checkDiameter', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        size: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch('size', function(){
          if(scope.size.inner > scope.size.outer){
            element.addClass('warning');
          }
        }, true);

      }
    };
```

In your css:

```
.warning-message {
  display: none;
}
.warning .warning-message {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yeha but then I need two controllers? Would be smooth if I could do it all in one.

Comment: Why do you need two controllers?

Comment: sorry, I mean two directives, warningMessage and checkDiameter. Possible to only have one?

Comment: you don't need a directive, ng-class should be enough.